# Flutter: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification from a device to another but when I sent it I got in the receiver device :

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 8876): broadcast received for message
E/FA      ( 8876): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See ...
```

[image]
I searched in the internet but no solution works from me so I add all the verification that I found that they need to be :

In the ProjectName/android/app/Build.gradle :

[image: In the Build.gradle.]

In the ProjectName/android/Build.gradle :

[image]

And I added the google-services.json in the path "ProjectName/android/app/"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the API Firebase Analytics is not installed so if you need to install it and activate it :

You must follow Literally the SDK setup and configuration of google:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Then restart your Pc or Mac.

Answer (score 14):

For Flutter devs: I only needed to upgrade my Gradle dependency

From: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'`

To: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'`

Then sync your Gradle file.

Comment: Nothing change in my case

Answer (score 13):

I had configured firebase with the help of flutterfire and thats when i started to see the error .

I added the Google services plugin in `android/app/build.gradle` which now looks like this :

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
```

Also not sure if it helps updated my Project level `android/build.gradle` Gradle file

From: classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1`

To: classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2`

Also remember to gradle sync your project .

With that my firebase analytics started working .

Comment: thanks! i also had to update my `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10` -> `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15`

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue,

Update your **app-level** build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'  
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics") 
}
```

Update your **project-level** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
}
```

make sure to use com.google.gms:google-services:**4.3.14**

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue, and the solution was adding this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In `android/app/build.gradle`, after the first `apply plugin` command.

My final `app/build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

Answer (score 3):

On my side, the issue was with `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I found when I get `FirebaseOptions.fromResource(context)` it was returning null.

It was happening because default `FirebaseOptions` config picks **package** name from `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It was missing when I created new Flutter app.

Make sure that the `package` attribute is there in the manifest tag.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.beautiful.app">
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, I have to change the version of `com.google.gms.google-services` inside the `settings.gradle` file.

FROM

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
}
```

TO

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your **settings.gradle** file

```
id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.1" apply false
```

If your gradle is not migrated you can migrate it by following [link.](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply)

Answer (score 0):

just revert to `"classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'"` in `android/build.girdle`

if you are migrating Android ....

in `android /settings.gradle`
add this in plugins

```
 id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.14" apply false
```

Answer (score -1):

Just deactivate ur flutter cli and activate it f
Firebase analytics will be enabled