# Flutter Push Notifications Error Analytics: Missing google_app_id

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, firebase-analytics

I am trying to implement push notifications in my Android app. When I send the notification I get this error:

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 8876): broadcast received for message
E/FA      ( 8876): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See ...
```

The console looks like this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZkJx.png
```

I have found multiple answers on the internet but I could not figure out what works. My current build.gradle, bot h in the app and project look like this:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "hu.android.trainhungary.service"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "hu.android.trainhungary.service"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have implemented firebase through the Flutterfire CLI. I have tried to manually add the steps provided by google to connect the app but I get errors and cannot make it work.
I cannot manage to implement and put Firebase Analytics into those, I dont know why.

I have tried looking at this, this is exactly what issue I have but I cannot manage to work: [Flutter: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896302/flutter-missing-google-app-id-firebase-analytics-disabled)

Thank you for helping me out!!