# Getting this Warning in console When i close the app

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, console

E/FA      (25298): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See
E/FA      (25298): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See W/example.kbc_ap(25298): Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 150 to 100
D/Linux   (25298): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.kbc_app :443
D/Linux   (25298): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.kbc_app :443

this error threw when i exit from application but application run in background.

I want to remove  this can you help me Community?
When i was close the app this warning threw in console.
What should i do for this?
i am using the flutter and Dart.

[image: E/FA (25298): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See E/FA (25298): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See W/example.kbc_ap(25298): Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 150 to 100]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77168724/21590733