# Error - Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-analytics

I got this error when enabled Firebase Analytics in my Android app. And the Analytics didn't show in the dashboard.

```
E/FA      ( 7298): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics is disabled.
```

I am using the same codebase for Firebase two projects using flavoring techniques for both UAT and PROD. I have already implemented Crashlytics and it works fine for both iOS and Android.

I tried the solutions in this link, but they didn't work for me.[Flutter: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896302/flutter-missing-google-app-id-firebase-analytics-disabled)

1. `app/build.gradle`
   [image]
2. `build.gradle`
   [image]
3. File structure
   [image]
4. Firebase Option Dart File

[image]

Comment: you have app id in google services.json?

Comment: Hi @MunsifAli Yea I have

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: This link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77315461/4373661