# Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled After Migrate Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

I've just migrated Flutter's Gradle plugins by following this [official link](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply).
However, I got the error says `Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled`.

I tried looking for solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896302/flutter-missing-google-app-id-firebase-analytics-disabled) since I got the same error, but the solutions says I have to add `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.3')` and `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'` to the app-level build.gradle file.

When I did it, I got the error

> Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                │
> │ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, │
> │ then update /Users/settasit/FlutterDev/lune/android/build.gradle:                     │
> │ ext.kotlin_version = ''

But `ext.kotlin_version = ''` was already removed when I migrated the project.

This is my app-level build.gradle file.

```
    plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.settasit.lune"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.settasit.lune"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

This is my project-level build.gradle file

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my settings.gradle file

```
    pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

How can I get firebase analytics with the migrated version of Android flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I just have to follow this section

```
#Examples: 
Google Mobile Services and Crashlytics
```

in the [official link](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply).

My bad.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).