# What is correct firebase config after upgrade flutter 3.19.X

Tags: android, flutter

The firebase analytic function worked well in my app until version 3.16.

However, after recently upgrading to 3.19, a strange phenomenon appeared on both Android and iOS.

Even after building and distributing the app, the new version is not displayed in Google Analytics.

Additionally, the following errors were detected:

```
03-13 16:51:35.504 E/FA (32235): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
```

I checked many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896302/flutter-missing-google-app-id-firebase-analytics-disabled) but it isn't hlep me

this is my `android/settings.gradle` file:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.9.9" apply false
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
}

include ":app"
```

and this is `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is `app/build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }


    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.app.example"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        // crash BUG - TODO
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#gradle
        // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83596
        ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a', 'x86_64' }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "api"
    productFlavors {
        ...
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    // implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}
```

Comment: Can you try to flutter clean, and check.

Comment: Thanks, after change this part `id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false` I didn't run `flutter clean`